# Email verification link redirecting to Login

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

The goal I want to achieve is to send users an email verification notification when they register via an API endpoint in a Laravel 5.8 project. To do that, I have done the following

1. Ensured the `App\User` implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail` contract

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    ...
}
```

2. User table has the `email_verified_at` column
3. Set `verify` to true in `web.php`

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

4. Send the notification in the register method of custom registeration controller `AuthController` like this

```
public function register(Request $request) {
    $user = User::create([
        'firstname' => $request->firstname,
        'lastname'  => $request->lastname,
        'username'  => $request->username,
        'password'  => bcrypt($request->password)
    ]);

    if ($user) {
        $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
    }
}
```

I get the email notification but the link redirects me to the login page. Why is this happening instead of actually verifying the email?

Please note that my `users` table does not have the `email` column, it uses a `username` column for storing emails instead.

Comment: The verify linked URL requires authentication. Please show that code. Not the email sender code.

Comment: What authentication? The documentation doesn't say anything about authentication so forgive me for asking

Comment: It's still not clear the code you are talking about. At the moment, the verify link from the email takes me straight to the login page. Of course the login page will ask for email/password to authenticate the user, in my case I cannot login with email since I don't have that field. I am storing emails using the username field. Keep in mind that this an API only project and I have a separate API for login

Comment: Ohhh, sorry  I was under the impression that the link in the email `emaillink.com/linkurl.php` was being redirected to the login. Are you saying the link on the email goes **directly** to the login script? `emaillink.com/login.php`. If so; please **`edit`** and clarify your question. Thank you

Comment: Can you post the exact email link in the email?